# How to set multilines for text?

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, google-translate

So I have a translator widget that was taken from Google Translate and it all works fine. When the input text is translated, the results are in the form of text (not textfield). In the case where I write a long paragraph for translation, I could implement "`keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline, maxLines: null,`" for textfield but I do not know how to do the same for text. Is there something for text widget too?

Currently, the translator widget looks like this:
[image: Translator Widget]

I want the grey area to have multiple lines where I can scroll through it.

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 350.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                focusNode: this.widget.focusNode,
                controller: this._textEditingController,
                onChanged: this._onTextChanged,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  suffixIcon: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (this._textEditingController.text != "") {
                        this.setState(() {
                          this._textEditingController.clear();
                          this._textTranslated = "";
                        });
                      } else {
                        this.widget.onCloseClicked(false);
                      }
                    },
                    child: new Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    shape: new CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  this._textTranslated,
                  softWrap: true,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[700], fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `Text` in a [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html):

```
Flexible(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          this._textTranslated,
          softWrap: true,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[700], fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: It gives me the RenderFlex overflowed error.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong with the order of the widgets, the `Flexible` should wrap the `SingleChildScrollView`. Let me edit my post